# Audio in phoneGap will not stop

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to make the play/stop the same element. The audio file plays perfectly but will not stop on second "click."

```
var audio = null;
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    audio = new Media("/android_asset/www/song.mp3", 

            if (audio) {
                audio.stop();
            }

    );
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickhere').click(function(event){ 
        audio.play();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing stop only fires when the page is first loaded. It won't fire again when you press 'clickhere'. So, you need to add a toggle to the clickhere part to toggle playing on and off. Something like this:

```
var playing = false;

$('#clickhere').click(function(event)
{
    if (playing)
    {
        audio.stop();
        playing = false;
    }
    else
    {
        audio.play();
        playing = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to pause playing, you can substitute audio.pause();

Comment: Possibly you could also use audio.isPlaying as Gautham has suggested, rather than rolling your own Boolean, but I don't remember that from the PhoneGap specs. Perhaps it'd been added since I last looked or I missed it.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly. I don't believe isPlaying() in phoneGap.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to do this:

```
  if (audio.isPlaying()) {
            audio.stop();
        }
```